# Can someone help resolve confusion over Blender’s GPU not support on macOS?

Tags: macos, imac, graphics

I'm not very tech-savvy so bear with me here. I want to use the newest version of Blender on my iMac. It is a late 2013 model with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 1 GB graphics card. More info below:
[image]

According to Blender's hardware requirements, my OS should be able to run the latest software version, yet I get errors when I try to open it. It is most likely there is an issue with the graphics card, but I am not exactly sure what the issue with the graphics is. I was told by the developers I need a GPU with "Metal 2.2 support" and that "Intel Macs without an AMD GPU require a Skylake processor or higher." What exactly is the issue with my computer and what is the best way to resolve it?

More info here:
https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0

Answer (score 3):

If I read the [Blender requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/#:%7E:text=Intel%20GPUs.-,Apple,-Apple%20Silicon%3A%20macOS) correctly, you need an AMD GPU or at least an Intel Skylake CPU on Intel Macs.

[image]

Your Mac has neither (Skylake CPUs have only been used from the late 2015 iMacs onwards).

You could try [older versions](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/#:%7E:text=and%20OpenGL%201.4-,macOS,-Blender%203.6%20supports) of Blender ([3.6](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/3-6/) might work).

Comment: Would updating the OS possibly help with this?

Comment: @ethan the limiting factor is hardware (CPU and GPU), an OS upgrade doesn’t change that.